# Is D statically compiled?

Tags: dynamic, compiler-construction, static, jit

Wikipedia says it has a garbage collector, yet I never heard of any JIT compiler for it (e.g. JRE, CLR, ect). Does it compile at run-time or compile-time?

Answer (score 0):

D is compiled (at compile time, natch).

D has an optional garbage collector. GC is orthogonal to static/dynamic compilation.

There are other examples of GCed, static languages without JIT compilation, like Eiffel.